# Errors in import multiple csv files into QGIS

Tags: python, qgis

I want to import multiple csv files into QGIS 3.2. It shows that "TypeError: QgsProject.addMapLayers(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'". I am new to QGIS and get confused. Here is my code. Thanks in advance!

```
import os, glob
path_to_csv = "D:/Paper/Data/bga_new_coord/"
os.chdir(path_to_csv)

for fname in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + fname + "?delimiter={}&crs=epsg:28355&xField={}&yField={}".format(";","xcoord","ycoord")
    name=fname.replace('.csv', '')
    lyr=QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'delimitedtext')
    lyr.isValid()
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(lyr)
```

And the Error is

```
TypeError: QgsProject.addMapLayers(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the function addMapLayer**s**() which expects a list of layers  ([ref](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#a5a3f52448a54a6bc97bf91509a755b67)) instead of a single layer.  Instead, try using [addMapLayer()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#a9e9cf6a97f67d17b26faf95a6124cdf4) , which expects a layer.

The error you get says basically the same thing: "Unexpectedly, I am being given a QgsVectorLayer (I wanted a list)"

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right, I need to use QgsProject.addMaplayer() rather than addMaplayers(). It works!